# The Apple Developer website is undergoing maintenance by fastlane

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-match

I did run `bundle exec fastlane match_development create:true` as usual.

My fastlane suddenly stopped working reporting apple developer website is under maintenance.

and take look the error information.

Please update using `bundle update fastlane`
/Users/knight.lu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spaceship-0.38.1/lib/spaceship/client.rb:414:in `parse_response': [!]  (Spaceship::Client::UnexpectedResponse)

[image: fastlane-error]

Any idea about `The Apple Developer website is undergoing maintenance. For details, visit developer.apple.com/system-status.`

Comment: ... Is the site under maintenance?

Comment: Did not see anything about maintenance.By visit : developer.apple.com/system-status

Comment: @knight2016 Correct. I've complained on twitter but maybe no one updated the reporting website. So yes, it's down for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like they are changing api endpoints, but getting mixed issues from people. [Follow the current issue on fastlane here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/8209).

The fix will probably require a fastlane update.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for now. Looks like Apple changes API somehow. But you can use match in readonly mode and update PPs manually: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/8208

Answer (score 0):

You can check all services here
[Apple Developer System Status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/)